# Android Ksoap2 library - Duplicate classes

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2, ksoap

I added ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar file to app/lib, in my project.

Next, in Android Studio, right clicked in the file and clicked "Add as library".

Now, I can't run the app because of the following error:

> Duplicate class okio.AsyncTimeout found in modules
> jetified-ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies
> (ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar) and
> jetified-okio-1.6.0 (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0)

Gradle project file where the lib was added:

```
dependencies {
    ....
    implementation files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar')  
}
```

I'm aware of some posts with similar error, and also Google documentation about it, but I'm not being able to relate that info to my problem.

Can you please help?

If you need me to provide more info in order for you to help, please ask.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Add gradle file where you add the library.

Comment: Done in the question, @TheLibrarian

Comment: Well, `-with-dependencies` says the most of it. I am assuming you are using `okio:okio` in the app?

Comment: I'm using 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.0'. I believe okio is part of it.

Comment: I interprete that your suggestion was to use the jar without dependencies. Problem is with that one, there are parts of my code which don't work because of missing classes.

Comment: Basically yes. The thing is that with that jar you are bringing some dependencies that you already have in the project and it's up to you how you solve that. One of the ways is to explicitly say that import of the library shouldn't bring certain dependencies with it. [Doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#exclude_dependencies)